# Rails DateTime date from string -> invalid date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, strptime

I'm currently working on a rails project and I need to create a DateTime object from a string.

Currently I have the following code:

```
datetime = DateTime.strptime(items[0] << 'T' << items[1], '%d.%m.%YT%H:%M:%S')
```

The string created by items[0] << 'T' << items[1] is for example 25.01.2012T18:25:47

But the I get the following error message "invalid date"

If I print the string to the rails server console it seems to be correct and if I replace "items[0] << 'T' << items[1]" with a valid string in the strptime method (e.g. 25.01.2012T18:25:47) it works, but I have no idea why the conversion to a DateTime object fails if i use the concatinated string...

Does anyone got an idea?

Best regards

Comment: That should work fine, what's going on that you're not showing us? And you do know that you're modifying `items[0]`, right? You'd probably be better off with `items[0] + 'T' + items[1]` or `"#{items[0]}T#{items[1]}"`.

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions, but none of them worked :( I think theres nothing interesting else that I'm doing. I read an uploaded csv file and parse it line by line. Then I split the content at the ; character and put the results into the strptime method

Comment: Naaaa I think I got it... Stupid thing... The first line of the CSV file is some kind of headline and does not contain any data that is parsable by strptime ;) But thanks for your efforts anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can try (items[0] << 'T' << items[1]).to_datetime . It will give an object in DateTime format.